# Any way to have undeclared variables for algebraic expressions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function which is able to solve a system of linear equations using gauss-jordan elimination.

In the instance that the augmented matrix cannot be solved uniquely (due to a row of zeros), instead of assigning an arbitrary number to the free variable `t`, I'd like to use the undeclared variable `t` itself in the rest of the operations.

I've searched for other similar posts regarding undeclared variables and most of them suggest assigning it the value of `None`.
However, this doesn't do what I want since you end up with TypeErrors if you attempt to manipulate it algebraically:

```
t = None
4*t + 3*t
```

Does not give: `7t`

Is it possible to achieve such a thing?

Comment: http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html

Comment: “I've searched for other similar posts regarding undeclared variables and most of them suggest assigning it the value of `None`.” — No, that can’t work, you must have completely misunderstood those posts. They were probably talking about something completely unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use something like SymPy, which deals with symbolic values. The problem with basic Python is that a variable is simply a name for a value, and does not itself have a type. `4*t + 3*t` can't be simplified to `7*t`, because depending on the type of the value referenced by `t`, multiplication may not distribute (that is, it may be possible that `4*t + 3*t != 7*t`).

Here's an extremely contrived example that simply demonstrates that you *can*, in Python, define a type for which distributivity does not hold. (I'm using `__rmul__` rather than `__mul__` simply to allow `3*t` et al. as in your example.)

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __rmul__(self, x):
        return Foo(str(x) + self.name)

    def __add__(self, x):
        return Foo(str(self.name) + ' + ' + str(x.name))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The result is two different values:

```
>>> t = Foo('x')
>>> print 4*t + 3*t
4x + 3x
>>> print 7*t
7x
```